# WSDL Client: Works in Java: Need to translate to PhP Class

Tags: php, wsdl

I would appreciate any help. I've been working with php for a while but I'm not familiar with php Class objects. Our help desk server, (SysAid) offers a SOAP API with WSDL. Using their instructions, I was able to make the service operate as expected in Java: I'm trying to translate the working Java code into php and I find myself lost early on. Here's the "working" java code:

First obtained the WSDL (https://itsupport.ighr.com/services/SysaidApiService?wsdl)

## Next in a Java Class:

```
SysaidApiService service = (new     SysaidApiServiceService()).getSysaidApiServicePort();
long token = service.login("COMPANYNAME", "admin", "*******");
ApiServiceRequest sr = (ApiServiceRequest)service.loadById(token, new     ApiServiceRequest(), Integer.valueOf('?'));
sr.setPriority(4);
sr.setUrgency(5);
```

## service.save(token, sr);

This line of Java code seems to be the one that is defeating me...
    "SysaidApiService service = (new SysaidApiServiceService()).getSysaidApiServicePort();"

I can create the class, and obtain the WSDL download but the line to create the service object has me clueless. Any suggestions from the php brains will be really helpful.
Thanks, John D.